# Copying an array using functions

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, copy

I want to copy one array to another using functions. But the following code doesnot work. Please correct me and guide me how to do this simplest task. I am a beginner in programming.

```
#-----------------------------------------
def copy():

    a=b
# ========================================
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(5)

b = np.zeros(5)

copy()

print(a)
# ========================================
```

The above code displays `[1 1 1 1 1]` instead of `[0 0 0 0 0]`

I am getting correct answer while doing the same without using functions, as follows :

```
# ============================
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(5)

b = np.zeros(5)

a=b

print(a)
# ============================
```

Comment: refer to [link] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: In your function send b as argument as copy(b). Also simply use `a=b.copy()` it should works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def copy():
    a=b
```

This method is merely declaring a new local variable `a` and assigning it to `b`. Now if you had defined a global variable `b` earlier then `a` will take the value of that `b`. Otherwise, it'll throw an error saying `b` was not defined earlier.

In either case, this method does not touch the global variable `a`.

If you wanted to modify the global variable `a`, you need to tell python about it:

```
def copy():
    global a
    a = b
```

But this solution is not very clean (and overly complicated) for something as simple as assignment. I'd suggest sticking to the second version you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax :-

try this one-

```
def copy(a, b):
    a = b.copy()
    return a

a = np.ones(5)
b = np.zeros(5)

print(copy(a, b))
```